# Why are compound literals not part of C++ so far?

Tags: c++, c, compatibility, c99, compound-literals

I know that C & C++ are different languages standardized by different committees.

I know that like C efficiency has been a major design goal for C++ from the beginning. So, I think if any feature doesn't incur any runtime overhead & if it is efficient then it should be added into the language. The **`C99`** standard has some very useful & efficient features and one of them is ***compound literals***. I was reading about compiler literals [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-literals-c/).

Following is a program that shows the use of compound literals.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Structure to represent a 2D point
struct Point
{
   int x, y;
};

// Utility function to print a point
void printPoint(struct Point p)
{
   printf("%d, %d", p.x, p.y);
}

int main()
{
   // Calling printPoint() without creating any temporary
   // Point variable in main()
   printPoint((struct Point){2, 3});

   /*  Without compound literal, above statement would have
       been written as
       struct Point temp = {2, 3};
       printPoint(temp);  */

   return 0;
}
```

So, due to the use of compound literals there is no creation of an extra object of type `struct Point` as mentioned in the comments. So, isn't it efficient because it avoids the need for an extra operation copying objects? So, why does C++ still not support this useful feature? Are there any problems with compound literals?

I know that some compilers like `g++` support compound literals as an extension but it usually leads to unportable code & that code isn't strictly standard conforming. Is there any proposal to add this feature to C++ also? If C++ doesn't support any feature of C there must be some reason behind it & I want to know that reason.

Comment: `printPoint({2,3});` will work in C++ (>= C++11 I think)

Comment: @Mat: yes definitely. See http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UfxN5SQ5HUQhuAIj . I think you are talking about new brace initializer syntax introduced by C++11.

Comment: Who voted to close & Why? What's wrong in my question?

Comment: @Mat: So, Can I say that due to {} initialization syntax there is no need of compound literals in C++?

Comment: Because C++11 has {} initializers, you can have the pretty much the same syntax. And because in C++11 you can declare constructors `constexpr`, you can guarantee that the initialization may happen statically.

Comment: Voted to close because "why doesn't language X have this great must-have feature Y of language Z" questions are opinion-based and non-constructive. They sound like an attack on people who are in the business of creating language standards. Instead, ask "what feature similar to Y in language Z does language X provide?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that there is no need for compound literals in C++, because in some way, this functionality is already covered by its OOP capabilities (objects, constructors and so on).

You program may be simply rewritten in C++ as:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Point
{
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x, y; 
};

void printPoint(Point p)
{
    std::printf("%d, %d", p.x, p.y);
}

int main()
{
    printPoint(Point(2, 3)); // passing an anonymous object
}
```

Comment: If you go C++14 and use brace initialization, you also get pretty much the same syntax.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You mean [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)?

Comment: @Michael, no I meant what I said. Barring inadequate comiler support, there is no reason to avoid c++14, since it contains more than a few improvements

Comment: My point was that C++14 isn't a requirement for using that syntax.

Comment: what about pointers? you can not take address of a temporary.